# Range of QVector

Tags: qt, range, qvector

I am wondering how can I find the range between two elements in QVector using c++. 
When using C# it's easier, and looks like following:

```
QVector aaa;
aaa.getRange(item1, item2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear. By googling what .NET's getRange actually does, it seems to return given count of elements from given starting position. [`QVector<T> QVector::mid(int pos, int length = -1);`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qvector.html#mid) does the same with QVector.

Comment: Thank you. What is the equivalent of AddRange()? Because append not always works.

Comment: [operator+](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qvector.html#operator-2b) maybe?

Comment: I checked in some cases insert works. But mostly it works the right way for vectors, but not for QVectors. Thank you, I will check now that too.